# php code to loop 1 using if else...upto last date

Tags: php, mysql

**table receipt**

```
 coupondate  receipt
 02-05-2015    5
 02-09-2015    5
```

**i am selecting min coupondate   and max coupondate  from table...**

below is my query..

```
SELECT RE.*,min(RE.coupondate) As mindate,max(RE.coupondate) As Maxdate FROM receipt_entry RE  GROUP BY RE.receipt_no
```

**Next i used fromdate and todate textbox in my form.**

if user enter fromdate = 01-05-2015 and todate = 31-05-2015..then i am display all days between this two dates like below example....

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18  ......upto ....31
```

**i used below code to display all days between two date...**

```
<?php
$startdate = $_POST['fromdate']; 
$enddate = $_POST['todate'];
$start = date('d', strtotime($startdate));
$end=date('d', strtotime($enddate));
?>
<?php for ($x = $start; $x <= $end; $x++) {?>
    <th width="58%"><?php echo $x; ?></th>
    <?php } ?>
```

**Now what i need is ...**

I need to print 1 starts from $row(mindate) and print continously upto last day.that is 31

**Expected output is**

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 ....31
    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1      1
```

**i try below code to print 1 which starts from mindate and end on 31.**

**but my code only display 1 below mindate..thats it...**

```
<?php  if (is_array($data)) { foreach($data as $row)    {   ?>
<tbody>
    <tr>                    
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['customer_name']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['startingdate']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['coupondate']); ?></td>

        <?php for ($x = $start; $x <= $end; $x++) { ?>  

            <?php if($row['mindate']== $x) { ?> 
            <td>1</td>          
            <?php } else {?>
            <td>-</td>
            <?php } ?>  

        <?php } ?>  
    </tr>
    <?php } }?>
```

**I am getting below output..**

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 ....31
-   1  -  -  -  -   -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -      -
```

Comment: `$row['mindate']` is a date and `$x`  is an integer. Am I correct?

Comment: Your output is correct. `$row['mindate']` can only be one single date, not a range. Check your query. `SELECT RE.*,min(RE.coupondate) As mindate,max(RE.coupondate) As Maxdate`. So, in your loop there is only one date that can validate your if condition

Comment: but what to do to get my expected output..plz...help...if you understand my problem...

Comment: i need to print 1 which starts from my mindate upto last day 31..